# Positioned spans being clipped in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

I'm trying to position a label above inline sections containing a set of spans, but I'm finding that Chrome appears to be clipping the labels weirdly. Take a look at these two screenshots:

**In Firefox:**

[image]

**In Chrome:**

[image]

If you look at the screenshot from Chrome, you can see the labels are being clipped based on the start point of the next label. The desired result would be the same as the Firefox screenshot, where the labels go all the way up to the end of the line.

Here is the code used for these two examples:

```css
.section {
  position: relative;
  border-right: solid 1px #000;
}
.section-title {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
.pieces {
  font-family: monospace;
}
.pieces span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 5px 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="section">
    <span class="section-title">Really long title is really long</span>
<span class="pieces">
        <span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span>
</span>
</span>
<span class="section">
    <span class="section-title">Really long title is really long</span>
<span class="pieces">
        <span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span>
</span>
</span>
<span class="section">
    <span class="section-title">Really long title is really long</span>
<span class="pieces">
        <span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span>
</span>
</span>
<span class="section">
    <span class="section-title">Really long title is really long</span>
<span class="pieces">
        <span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span>
</span>
</span>
```

Is this a known Chrome/WebKit bug? Is it possible to fix without drastically modifying the HTML?

Comment: Working fine in my browser(Chrome)

Comment: @MegaMind Have you tried resizing the window so they overlap? I've experienced this problem in both Chrome and nw.js (latest version).

Comment: yes i resized chrome. the text got clipped. But the same is happening with Firefox too.

Comment: @MegaMind Is it? That didn't happen for me.. I don't mean the clipping that occurs when the text reaches the end of the line.. thats fine. I mean the clipping that appears to occur at the starting point of the next section.

Comment: You can use `display : inline-block` for the `section-title`. Maybe that will help you solve the problem.

Comment: @MegaMind If you look at the CSS, `section-title` does have that rule, but it is effectively overriden by the absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug in Chrome... it's a problem with the code, which Chrome interpreted in a way that it deemed logical.

Firstly, note that your `.section-title` is absolutely positioned and set with both `left` and `right`. This means:

1. It automatically becomes `display:block`.
2. It tries to be 5px from left, and 5px from right boundary of the parent.

Then, note that your parent `.section` is an inline element, since all `span` tags are inline by default. Therefore, it takes the width that it requires to accommodate its children. Your long line of `00` overflows to the next row, and hence the "right boundary" also overflows to the next row.

Being an obedient element, `.section-title` tries its best to stay 5px away from that right border, which is now very much nearer. Hence, the `text-overflow: ellipsis` correctly kicks in.

To fix your code:

1. Having `display: inline-block` for an absolutely positioned element is useless. It confuses. Take it out.
2. Don't set it to `right:5px`. Take it out. (this is the only fix that matters, actually).
3. Please do feedback to the author who wrote this HTML that the HTML vocabulary is more than just `<span>`. It's ridiculous to use only `<span>` for everything when more logical tags like `<section>`, `<h1>-<h6>` will fit the content better.

Comment: The `right:5px` rule is there for a reason: it prevents the text from overflowing into the next section if two sections are beside each other (to demonstrate this you can try removing some of the 00 spans to make the section shorter than the title text), and prevents overflowing off the edge of the parent.
The `display:inline-block` was probably just a left-over style from past testing..

Comment: Actually, `right:5px` doesn't prevent overflow per se, but only by virtue that the element always positions itself to be 5px away from the right border. You can achieve the same effect by setting `width` to be 100% or less, which ensures it never overflows the parent. Of course, it wouldn't solve your problem. You have to choose: either let `.section-title` has its width overflow its parent, or not.

Comment: Thats what I mean.. What I want to know (and what the whole point of this question actually is) is if/how it would be possible to not have it overflow the parent, and not be clipped in this way.